# iPhone: Separate Stroke and Fill not working

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I have the following code:

```
    if (self.graphic.fillColor)
    {
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.graphic.fillColor);
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill);
    }

    if (self.graphic.strokeColor)
    {
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.graphic.strokeColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.graphic.strokeWidth);
        CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
    }
```

In a certain instance, I am loading a graphic object which has a `fillColor` and a `strokeColor`. When I do this, the fill is completed, but the stroke is not drawn at all (and I've double checked to see if there are any bugs with the assigning of the stroke values, and everything looks OK). Why is this? If you're doing these two together, do you need to do them at the same time ie in one `CGContextDrawPath`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hen you call `CGContextDrawPath`, CoreGraphics draw (fill or stroke) the `CGPathRef` that you previously added to the context, **and then remove the `CGPathRef` from that context** has it has been used.

So if you have called `CGContextDrawPath` in your first "if" condition, you simply need to re-add your `CGPathRef` to your context before you can draw it again.

---

Besides, it would be more effective to add your path to your context only if you need to either fill or stroke it (or both) and don't add it if neither `fillColor` nor `strokeColor` is nil (ne need to build/add your path if you won't fill nor stroke it).

As you pointed out yourself, anyway, there is a constant to both fill and stroke at the same time, called `kCGPathFillStroke`. So your code may look like this:

```
// Don't draw anything if both colors are nil
if (self.graphic.fillColor || self.graphic.strokeColor)
{
  // Build and add your CGPathRef here
  CGPathRef path = ...
  CGContextAddPath(context, path);

  // Then either fill, stroke, or fillstroke the path.
  CGPathDrawingMode mode;
  if (self.graphic.fillColor)
  {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, self.graphic.fillColor);
    mode = kCGPathFill;
  }
  if (self.graphic.strokeColor)
  {
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.graphic.strokeColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.graphic.strokeWidth);
    // if we also have a fillcolor, use fillstroke mode. Else just use stroke.
    mode = (self.graphic.fillColor) ? kCGPathFillStroke : kCGPathStroke;
  }
  CGContextDrawPath(context, mode);
}
```

That way:

- if you only have `fillColor` and no `strokeColor`, you will only set the fill color and use `kCGPathFill`.
- if you only have `strokeColor` and no `fillColor`, you will only set stroke color and line with, and use `kCGPathStroke`
- if you have both colors assigned, you will set both fill color, stroke color and line with, and use `kCGPathFillStroke`.

Comment: Thanks for that long response. is it more efficient to use kCGPathFillStroke for the case when it's both?

Comment: Indeed! I forgot the existence of this constant that can both stroke and fill at the same time ;) Will edit my answer accordingly !